# How do I preserve column grouping in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am using Libreoffice 5.2.0.4

In Calc (the spreadsheet), I am trying to build an appointment book. Since this is designed a bit like a calendar, I have rows and columns that I want to be able to group.

If there is a public holiday we are closed and no appointments. So I want to be able to click once, and close a bunch of columns. Otherwise these columns are just blank because we have no appointments written down on that day.

I can group the rows without issue. (Actually learned how to do this from another Superuser post!)

I can also group the columns. But unlike for the rows, I cannot save my groupings. IE when the worksheet is open, I can group and manipulate the cell appearances. But once I save and close and open again, the groupings for columns vanish. Which defeats the purpose of having an appointment book that can't save changes, at least for this specific grouping thing.

[image: Rows and Columns Q]

[image: Rows and Columns Q2]

[image: Rows and Columns Q3]

*(click on image for larger view)*

Answer (score 1):

You must save in ODF format for column groupings to be saved.

[image: warning when saving as .xlsx]

Excel can read ODF format, or you can export a copy as PDF.  But saving as XLSX from Calc or saving as ODF from Excel is going to result in problems.